# Removing a handler from a button and add another handler to it On a button click in code behind

Tags: asp.net

I a button

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnShowWelcomeMessage"
                        OnClick="btnShowWelcomeMessage_OnClick" Text="Cancel" />
```

On click of following button I want to remove handler associated with the above button & bind some other handler.

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Show Additional Data"
        ID="btnFindAddlInvoices" OnClick="btnShowAddlData_OnClick" />
```

I am trying this:

```
 protected void btnShowAddlData_OnClick(object Sender, EventArgs E)
    {
        try
        {
            btnShowWelcomeMessage.Click -= new EventHandler(btnShowWelcomeMessage_OnClick);
            btnShowWelcomeMessage.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            ExceptionLog.LogErrorDetails(Ex);
        }
    }
```

After clicking on btnShowAddlData button i.e. after executing the above code also, on click of btnShowWelcomeMessage it's original handler btnShowWelcomeMessage_OnClick is getting executed.

Comment: it will work only if you place it in page load or page init,The event handler needs to be bound for every request regardless of whether or not the page is being posted back. The binding of the event handler is lost at the start of each page request. Event handlers for buttons are typically bound in Page_Load.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve by doing this `even you can use delegates here`

Comment: How delegates can be used here? @Ganesh_Devlekar